# Code Igniter problem, Getting a simple SQL error, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxf8QDQqmjw) series to learn to make a login script.
Ive done the entire tutorial, but I Keep getting thrown this error.

```
I am using CodeIgniter Framework 2.02
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'anil' in 'where clause'
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = anil AND password = password
Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\c_login\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330<
```

Here is the function in my model doing the SQL:

```
function check_login($username, $password)
  {
    $sha1_password = sha1($password);

    // The Guy uses ' ? ' in the video for the below statement and it works
    // I tried replacing ? with $username & $password, but it didnt work..
    // When I use the ?, I think it does query the DB, but I get the error
    // Incorrect Username or Password, Even though it is correct.
    // I only have 1 record on my DB, db = c_login, table=users
    // Fields are user_id   username    password    email   name

    $query_str = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
    $result = $this->db->query($query_str, $username, $sha1_password);

    if($result->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $result->row[0]->user_id;
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 

    }
}
```

Also, if needed, here is my login function in my controller..

```
    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|max_length[50]|xss_clean');

        // If form_validation has NOT been run, load the view login form
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)            
        {
            $this->load->view('view_login');
        }
        else // Else process login
        {
            // Process input and login
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $user_id = $this->User_model->check_login($username, $password);

            if( ! $user_id)
            {
                // Login Failed Error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE);
                redirect('user/login');
            }
            else
            {
                // Log them in

                $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                'logged_in' => TRUE, 
                                'user_id' => $user_id
                                                    ));

                redirect('user/main_page');
            }

        }

    }
```

So basically, It keeps saying Incorrect Username or Password if I use the Question marks in the SQL query, but if I replace them with the variables $username & $password, I get the error in the first block of code. Error Number: 1054,
What am I doing wrong? I could swear its something so simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try taking advantage of the Active Record and do the following (verbose version for clarity):

```
  function check_login($username, $password)
  {
    $sha1_password = sha1($password);

    $this->db->select('user_id');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $sha1_password);
    $result = $this->db->get('users');

    if($result->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $row = $result->row();
        return $row->user_id;
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Data is automatically escaped so you don't need to worry about that. In controller, rewrite this part to:

```
  if($user_id == FALSE)
  {
     $this->session->set_flashdata('login_error', TRUE);
     redirect('user/login', 'refresh');
  }
  else
  {
      $this->session->set_userdata(array(
                                       'logged_in' => TRUE, 
                                       'user_id' => $user_id
                                    ));

      redirect('user/main_page', 'refresh');
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

this

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = anil AND password = password
```

would probably be fixed by using an `'`:

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'anil' AND password = 'password'
```

Like this it gets parsed as a string, not as a column name.

Comment: This worked to get rid of the error!, Thanks!, but I still cant login, I keep getting incorrect username and password, even though they are both correct, any ideas?

Comment: Is the hashed password you query gets the same as in your database?

Comment: Yes its the same, I temporarly bypassed the sha1 hashing system, just to see if it does it normally, and it didnt work, I edited mysql username and password manually with plain text passwords, and edited the code above to exclude the sha1 and just use plain text, it still didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your query bindings:

```
$result = $this->db->query($query_str, array($username, $sha1_password));
```

Comment: I did this the first time round, it didnt work, i forgot to include it above in the example, I've just tried it again, Im getting the same incorrect user and password for some reason.